# css transitions - animate responsive repositioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-transitions

```
<div id="a">my content blah blah .....</div>
<div id="b" style="display: none">magic content blah blah</div>
<div id="c">other stuff</div>
```

in js (jQuery) i use`$("#b").fadeIn()` and `$("#b").fadeOut()` to control the visibility of div#b

when jQuery Animation starts/ends the last div (div#c) is moved (by the Browser) up(under div#a) (on fadeOut) and down (under div#b) (on fadeIn)

how can i animate this moves of div#c? (Moving smoothly the div(#c) up and down) with css transitions.

with 'moves' i mean element repositioning performed by browser when a item disappears (fadeOut) or when the 'resolution' of the screen changes (responsive adapt)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`, you're changing the element from `display: whatever` to `display: none;`, and vice-versa. There are no transition properties on any DOM Elements with the display method - so you're best off switching to a CSS3 transition instead https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp , A mixture of transitional properties such as `opacity`, `visibility` and `max-height`s! Otherwise, you could look into using a JS library such as GSAP - https://greensock.com/gsap